# Regenerate access token request at given interval using JMeter

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have to regenerate my access token after an interval of 1 hour. All these APIs require an OAuth-based access token, which I generate at the start of the test and save in a variable that is then used by other subsequent API calls.

I have used flow control action after the http request and Token can be passed from one thread group to another using __setProperty and __property() functions.

I don't want to send multiple authenticate request un-necessarily.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is is a question? The approach of:

1. Having a separate [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to generate/refresh the token with 1 thread and the required number of loops
2. Using [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler so it would run at given intervals
3. Using [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function in this Thread Group to store the token into a JMeter Property and [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or [__property()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) functions to read the value is correct.

If anything doesn't work we need to see:

- the configuration of the respective test element(s)
- [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file
- what JMeter properties and variables are defined (can be checked using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) combination)